# Convert every value into milliseconds

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Spinner which I want to use to configure time for a Task. In this case I cant to set the numeric value with Spinner and with Combobox to set the in hours or in minutes to convert the value:

```
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner();
        spinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 10000));
        spinner.setEditable(true);

        ComboBox comb = new ComboBox();
        comb.getItems().addAll(
            "Milliseconds",
            "Seconds",
            "Minutes",
            "Hours",
            "Days"
        );
        comb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        spinner.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val)
            {
                String value = comb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();

                long convertedValue = 0;

                switch (Integer.parseInt(spinner.getValue().toString()))
                {
                    case 1:
                        value = "Milliseconds";
                        convertedValue = Integer.parseInt((String) spinner.getValue());

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        value = "Seconds";
                        convertedValue = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis((long) spinner.getValue());

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        value = "Minutes";
                        convertedValue = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis((long) spinner.getValue());

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        value = "Hours";
                        convertedValue = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis((long) spinner.getValue());

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        value = "Days";
                        convertedValue = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis((long) spinner.getValue());

                        break;

                }

                System.out.println(">>>>> " + convertedValue);
            }
        });

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(spinner, comb);
        hb.setSpacing(50);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Spinner will always keep the value in milliseconds but based on combo box selection I need to convert for example 5 minutes into milliseconds. 
How I can implement this listener? And of course when I have 5000 milliseconds I would like to display them into minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one? I guess the main mistake in your code-example is inside the switch-statement where you switch for the spinner value instead the combobox-value.
This example corrrects your problem and in the System.out.println(...) at the end you can see the original value and the converted value to be printed. You can use it further in your application.

Edit: I added the hint in your comment. Now you can enter any time in Milliseconds, Seconds, ... (Remember to press enter - otherwise the event is not triggered) then after the combobox is changed your changed value is written into the spinner - you want want to enlarge the maximumvalue in the spinner to allow higher entries in milliseconds).
It is also based on integer-calculation. So rounding adjustments for the time will be lost.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    long    milliSeconds;
    String  unitAtLastChange;
    int     originalValue;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>();
        spinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 10000));
        spinner.setEditable(true);

        ComboBox<String> comb = new ComboBox<>();
        comb.getItems().addAll("Milliseconds", "Seconds", "Minutes", "Hours", "Days");
        comb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        this.unitAtLastChange = comb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        spinner.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Integer> ov, Integer old_val, Integer new_val) {
                MainApp.this.unitAtLastChange = comb.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                MainApp.this.originalValue = new_val.intValue();

                switch (MainApp.this.unitAtLastChange) {
                    case "Milliseconds":
                        MainApp.this.milliSeconds = new_val.intValue();

                        break;
                    case "Seconds":
                        MainApp.this.milliSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(new_val.intValue());

                        break;
                    case "Minutes":
                        MainApp.this.milliSeconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(new_val.intValue());

                        break;
                    case "Hours":
                        MainApp.this.milliSeconds = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(new_val.intValue());

                        break;
                    case "Days":
                        MainApp.this.milliSeconds = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(new_val.intValue());
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error - wrong value");

                }

                System.out.println("Converted: " + MainApp.this.originalValue + " " + MainApp.this.unitAtLastChange + " Original: "
                        + MainApp.this.milliSeconds + " Milliseconds");
            }
        });

        comb.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                switch (newValue) {
                    case "Milliseconds":
                        MainApp.this.originalValue = (int) MainApp.this.milliSeconds;

                        break;
                    case "Seconds":
                        MainApp.this.originalValue = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(MainApp.this.milliSeconds);

                        break;
                    case "Minutes":
                        MainApp.this.originalValue = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(MainApp.this.milliSeconds);

                        break;
                    case "Hours":
                        MainApp.this.originalValue = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(MainApp.this.milliSeconds);

                        break;
                    case "Days":
                        MainApp.this.originalValue = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(MainApp.this.milliSeconds);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error - wrong value");

                }
                spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(Integer.valueOf(MainApp.this.originalValue));
            }
        });

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(spinner, comb);
        hb.setSpacing(50);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to ask one more thing. When I have the value in millisecond already defined how I can convert it into Spinner based on selected ComboBox?

Comment: Fyi: What mainly is changed is that now the combobox also has an listener. And on this listener the value of the spinner is changed to the new selected unit in the combobox

Comment: Are there any options for shrinking the code some how? Maybe by using binding?

Comment: Why not use a `ComboBox<TimeUnit>`?